# Parse Promise return a value

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a function that runs a query (returning a promise) and then manipulates the returned data. How do I get the calling function to have access to the **manipulated** data?

The call is like this:

```
getAgeGroupList().then(function (result) {
        // Would like to access manipulated data here.
    });
```

And the function is as below. The `query.find()` returns a Promise in Parse.

```
function getAgeGroupList(){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Fixtures_and_results");
    return query.find({
        success: function(results) {
             /* Manipulate results here, then return manipulated data */
             // How do I return the manipulated data? e.g return(newArray)
        },
        error: function(error) {  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You would need to return the promise from `getAgeGroupList()` and then resolve the promise in your success function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `query.find` returns a promise, then you don't want to use `success` and `error` handlers; instead, use `then` to manipulate the value:

```
function getAgeGroupList(){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Fixtures_and_results");
    return query.find().then(results => {
        // Manipulate results here
        return updatedResults;
    });
}
```

That will return a new promise that will resolve with your manipulated results rather than the original. This is *promise chaining*.

If the `query.find` call fails, its promise will reject, and the promise created by `then` will pass that rejection along (without calling the `then` handler).

---

I used an arrow function above, but looking at your code, it doesn't use any ES2015+ features other than promises. So you may want:

```
function getAgeGroupList(){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Fixtures_and_results");
    return query.find().then(function(results) { // <=== Changed to traditional function
        // Manipulate results here
        return updatedResults;
    });
}
```

instead.

Comment: So, `success` cannot return in the chain like `then()`?

Comment: @SimpleOne: I have no idea; the Parse documentation should say. I can't think why one would want to use an old-style callback rather than `then` if `find` returns a promise. One of the great things about promises is that they have standard, known semantics (along with being composable, etc.).

Comment: @SimpleOne: ...sigh, but of course, parse.com is offline now having been discontinued. I expect docs must be available *somewhere*. Edit: [Found some](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.Query.html#find), doesn't say anything about `success` being able to modify the results passing through.